# What is a Cached acessor in the context of DataBinding?

Tags: wpf, data-binding

I get this trace information  for the binding:

```
    System.Windows.Data Warning: 55 : Created BindingExpression (hash=45919010) for Binding (hash=4523055)
    System.Windows.Data Warning: 57 :   Path: 'IsEnvelopeFocused'
    System.Windows.Data Warning: 59 : BindingExpression (hash=45919010): Default mode resolved to TwoWay
    System.Windows.Data Warning: 60 : BindingExpression (hash=45919010): Default update trigger resolved to PropertyChanged
    System.Windows.Data Warning: 61 : BindingExpression (hash=45919010): Attach to System.Windows.Controls.DataGridCell.IsFocused (hash=42777048)
    System.Windows.Data Warning: 66 : BindingExpression (hash=45919010): Resolving source 
    System.Windows.Data Warning: 69 : BindingExpression (hash=45919010): Found data context element: DataGridCell (hash=42777048) (OK)
    System.Windows.Data Warning: 77 : BindingExpression (hash=45919010): Activate with root item VulnerEnvelope (hash=53089570)

    System.Windows.Data Warning: 106 : BindingExpression (hash=45919010):   At level 0 using cached 
accessor for VulnerEnvelope.IsEnvelopeFocused: RuntimePropertyInfo(IsEnvelopeFocused)

    System.Windows.Data Warning: 103 : BindingExpression (hash=45919010): Replace item at level 0 with VulnerEnvelope (hash=53089570), using accessor RuntimePropertyInfo(IsEnvelopeFocused)
    System.Windows.Data Warning: 100 : BindingExpression (hash=45919010): GetValue at level 0 from VulnerEnvelope (hash=53089570) using RuntimePropertyInfo(IsEnvelopeFocused): 'False'
    System.Windows.Data Warning: 79 : BindingExpression (hash=45919010): TransferValue - got raw value 'False'
```

I also use converter to output data flow: `Target -> Source` and `Source -> Target`.
Besides this I output binding information for attached property at its every change.
Binding stays active but Source and Target do not synchronize. I don't know what is the cause of this broken functionality and as VS2012 prints Warning 106 in red I think the problem is somewhere near this message.

And here is the binding:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Width="*" CanUserResize="True" CanUserSort="True" Header=" Title "
                                                SortMemberPath=".">
  <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellStyle>
    <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
      <Setter Property="Helpers:FocusHelper.IsFocused" Value="{Binding IsEnvelopeFocused, Converter={StaticResource bdc}, PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel=High}"/>
    </Style>
  </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellStyle>
  <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <TextBlock Name="txtTitle" VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <TextBlock.Text>
          <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource TitleConverter}" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">
            <Binding Path="." />
            <Binding Path="DataContext.Language" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=UserControl}" />
          </MultiBinding>
        </TextBlock.Text>
      </TextBlock>
    </DataTemplate>
  </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Answer (score 1):

I realy do not know WHY but this street magic helped!

It was:

```
<Setter Property="Helpers:FocusHelper.IsFocused" Value="{Binding IsEnvelopeFocused,
                                Converter={StaticResource bdc}, 
                                PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel=High}"/>
```

It became:

```
<Setter Property="Helpers:FocusHelper.IsFocused" Value="{Binding DataContext.IsEnvelopeFocused, 
                                Converter={StaticResource bdc}, 
                                PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel=High, 
                                RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"/>
```

Data binding trace output changed:

```
System.Windows.Data Warning: 55 : Created BindingExpression (hash=52742621) for Binding (hash=33023833)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 57 :   Path: 'DataContext.IsEnvelopeFocused'
System.Windows.Data Warning: 59 : BindingExpression (hash=52742621): Default mode resolved to TwoWay
System.Windows.Data Warning: 60 : BindingExpression (hash=52742621): Default update trigger resolved to PropertyChanged
System.Windows.Data Warning: 61 : BindingExpression (hash=52742621): Attach to System.Windows.Controls.DataGridCell.IsFocused (hash=34022436)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 66 : BindingExpression (hash=52742621): Resolving source 
System.Windows.Data Warning: 69 : BindingExpression (hash=52742621): Found data context element: <null> (OK)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 71 :   RelativeSource.Self found DataGridCell (hash=34022436)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 77 : BindingExpression (hash=52742621): Activate with root item DataGridCell (hash=34022436)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 106 : BindingExpression (hash=52742621):   At level 0 using cached accessor for DataGridCell.DataContext: DependencyProperty(DataContext)

System.Windows.Data Warning: 103 : BindingExpression (hash=52742621): Replace item at level 0 with DataGridCell (hash=34022436), using accessor DependencyProperty(DataContext)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 100 : BindingExpression (hash=52742621): GetValue at level 0 from DataGridCell (hash=34022436) using DependencyProperty(DataContext): VulnerEnvelope (hash=14963839)

System.Windows.Data Warning: 106 : BindingExpression (hash=52742621):   At level 1 using cached accessor for VulnerEnvelope.IsEnvelopeFocused: RuntimePropertyInfo(IsEnvelopeFocused)

System.Windows.Data Warning: 103 : BindingExpression (hash=52742621): Replace item at level 1 with VulnerEnvelope (hash=14963839), using accessor RuntimePropertyInfo(IsEnvelopeFocused)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 100 : BindingExpression (hash=52742621): GetValue at level 1 from VulnerEnvelope (hash=14963839) using RuntimePropertyInfo(IsEnvelopeFocused): 'False'
System.Windows.Data Warning: 79 : BindingExpression (hash=52742621): TransferValue - got raw value 'False'
System.Windows.Data Warning: 81 : BindingExpression (hash=52742621): TransferValue - user's converter produced 'False'
System.Windows.Data Warning: 88 : BindingExpression (hash=52742621): TransferValue - using final value 'False'
```

And binding now works in both ways.
I thinks there's a broblem with DataGridCell's DataContext inheritance and style appplication.
To be exact the order matters here, I suppose.
If Style is applied first Data Binding tries to get not yet inherited DataContext and that somehow breaks binding causing no updates.
I'll try to reproduce this bug and if I manage to do it, I'll write to MS Connect.